# B360 Autodesk Forge not getting room geometry from linked files

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I've been trying to get room information / geometry from a linked model, and I was able to get the geometry of the rooms on the "New construction" phase view, and nothing else on that view, like walls geometry from linked models. On the other hand,I get the geometry of these walls on the other views, but, for some reason, not of the rooms.

I need to see all geometry on the same view so I can keep up with the work. I've already tried to use the `skipHiddenFragments:false` on the `loadDocumentNode` options and calling the `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job` POST Api endpoint with `generateMasterViews` advanced option and `x-ads-force` header on the request, all of this with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you're using the SVF2 file format, try and see if the same issue happens when you convert the Revit model into SVF(1). I've seen a case where the combination of SVF2 and `generateMasterViews` was causing some issues, so I'm wondering if this could be something similar.

Comment: And whether you're successful or not, if you wouldn't mind sharing the Revit model with us (confidentially - the file wouldn't be shared with anyone outside of Autodesk), we'd be happy to pass it on to the Model Derivative team for further investigation.